# How to add padding to navbar using Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I just want to add padding to *Vuetify* navbar. I used `px-number` but it won't work.

I tried this line of code but its not showing any sign of padding just default
`<v-app-bar color="deep-purple accent-4" dark px-10>`

I can use CSS to do that but its not proper.

[image]

[image]

Comment: <v-app-bar color="deep-purple accent-4" dark px-10>

Answer (score 0):

Padding needs to be in a class

```
<v-app-bar color="deep-purple accent-4" dark class="px-10">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vuetify premade classes due to "Spacing" in their docs (they offer only some "numbers") or make your custom classes in external CSS with your preferred padding, which I personally prefer more, because of better customizability.

Vuetify spacing:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/spacing/#spacing